# in postgres, is there an easy way to select several attr/val rows into one record?

Tags: sql, postgresql

if I have

```
create table t1( attr text primary key, val text );
insert into t1 values( 'attr1', 'val1' );
insert into t1 values( 'attr2', 'val3' );
insert into t1 values( 'attr3', 'val3' );
```

would like to `select` to return one row

```
attr1=>val1, attr2=>val2, attr3=>val3
```

right now doing conversion in javascript, but would be nice for `pg` to return the row itself

---

### Answer

based on @mu's answer, the query:

```
select replace( replace( replace( array_agg( hstore( attr, val ) )::text
   '"\"', '"'), 
   '\""', '"'),
   '\"=>\"', '":"')  from t1;
```

results in:

```
{"attr1":"val1","attr2":val2","attr3":"val3"}
```

which is quite nice JSON (as long as no quotes in values)

Comment: Run `insert into t1 (attr,val) values ('at"tr', 'v"a"l');` and re-run your query. You'll see that there's no escaping handling, so you'll get corrupt json.

Comment: @CraigRinger - you're right - thought I had put that in answer but had forgotten - will add.  btw, thanks for your answer - I too was hoping for a little stronger json support.  imho still need CREATE TABLE trigger to do real joson work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) installed then you could use [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
select array_agg(attr => val) from t1;
```

That would give you exactly the output you're looking for. Of course, whatever interface you're using would have to understand hstore and arrays or you'd have to unpack the results yourself; and if that was the case, it would probably be simpler to iterate over a simple `select attr, val from t1` query and build the data structure in JavaScript.

Comment: when run, get `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s)` with caret under '=>'.  on `create extension hstore` received message `WARNING:  => is deprecated as an operator name`

Comment: never mind: had not coerced `attr` into text in real table, ie, `array_agg( attr::text, val )` worked fine

Comment: @ccyoung: `attr => val` requires the hstore extension.

Comment: yes, got that.  problem was my being stupid about casting.  worked fine.  thanks for the help!  always appreciate your acumen.

Comment: @ccyoung: You might want to look into Craig's JSON approach if you can use it. Or at least make a note of it for when you upgrade.

Comment: Did you mean `select hstore( array_agg(attr), array_agg(val) ) from t1;` ? All key/value pairs in one hstore.

Comment: @CraigRinger: No, `array_agg(a => b)` will produce an array of hstores, it won't quite be a JavaScript-ish object but it will be one row. In real life I'd probably just iterate over `select attr, val from t1` and move on to more interesting problems though.

Comment: @muistooshort Agreed that it's a bit of an odd requirement. What's caught my interest is how hard this is to do with 9.2's json support. Looks like we really need an object constructor like `json(text[], json[])` and a `json_escape` function.

Answer (score 3):

I expected it to be possible to use `array_to_json` with `array_agg`. See the [PostgreSQL 9.2 json documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-json.html) for usage, and the [json91](https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91) module that backports the JSON functionality for use in PostgreSQL 9.1 until 9.2 is out, or use a 9.2 beta.

Unfortunately, it turns out there doesn't seem to be any suport for merging, aggregating, etc json at this point. That makes it surprisingly difficult to build JSON values.  I landed up just doing it with regular text operators, but that doesn't allow for quoting issues.

```
regress=# SELECT '{'||string_agg('"'||attr||'": "'||val||'"', ', ')||'}' FROM t1;
                      ?column?                       
-----------------------------------------------------
 {"attr1": "val1", "attr2": "val3", "attr3": "val3"}
(1 row)
```

See:

```
regress=# insert into t1 (attr,val) values ('at"tr', 'v"a"l');
INSERT 0 1
regress=# SELECT '{'||string_agg('"'||attr||'": "'||val||'"', ', ')||'}' FROM t1;
                               ?column?                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"attr1": "val1", "attr2": "val3", "attr3": "val3", "at"tr": "v"a"l"}
(1 row)

regress=# SELECT ('{'||string_agg('"'||attr||'": "'||val||'"', ', ')||'}')::json FROM t1;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  line 1: Token "tr" is invalid.
```

The same issue exists in the solution you added to your answer. For a good answer to that, we need functions something like `json_escape_literal`, and there isn't currently anything like that exposed to SQL.

The only safe approach I see with Pg's current json feature set is to produce an array of pairs, but that's no better than what you get with an ordinary row-oriented query.

```
regress=# SELECT  array_to_json( array_agg( array_to_json( ARRAY[attr, val] ) )) FROM t1;
                               array_to_json                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [["attr1","val1"],["attr2","val3"],["attr3","val3"],["at\"tr","v\"a\"l"]]
```

You can probably combine hstore and json to do what you want, but that's getting into extension soup. What this really needs is a json object constructor function that's equivalent to `hstore(text[],text[])` so you can do the json equivalent of:

```
select hstore( array_agg(attr), array_agg(val) ) from t1;
```

**UPDATE**: [pgsql-general mailing list post on this topic](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/501E19CE.6070500@ringerc.id.au)

Comment: There is a JavaScript PL for 9.2 which should make dealing with JSON much easier: http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/249-Using-PLV8-to-index-JSON.html

Comment: @ccyoung Odd, message must've been held. It's usually 404 for the first few mins until the archiver gets the message, but not for hours. The link will go live when the message goes through the list manager, anyway.